# In Monero GUI Beta 2, is rewarding the solo miner automatic?

Tags: mining, block-reward

I installed Monero GUI Beta 2, downloaded the blockchain and started to solo-mine. If the program finds a block and I'm rewarded, is this reward process automatic or should I do something to get my reward?

Thank you in advance...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you start solo mining, any block reward you find will appear in your wallet automatically, without any further action needed on your part. As a reminder, if you exit the daemon, you will have to start mining again, as the GUI merely instructs the dameon to mine.

Note that the likelihood of finding a block solo mining on an average computer is pretty small: currently, assuming 200 hashes a second, you can expect a block every... 1/(720 * 200 / 220e6), that is about 1500 days. However, if you do find a block, then you get 6.9*130 = $900 at current prices. So it's a lottery in exchange for helping the Monero network.

Good luck!

Comment: I downloaded Monero GUI beta 2 and specified a directory for my wallet. I downloaded the blockchain and connected. But that directory is empty!!! Where is my wallet?

Thanx in advance...

Comment: I believe the GUI stores wallets in ~/Monero or ~/MoneroWallets or similar directory by default. They might be there ? Also, if you specified a relative directory (ie, without a leading /), it might be in there as a subdirectory ?

Comment: I searched monero. Nothing... I specified D:\Monero\Wallet... Downloaded blockchain... But Wallet directory is empty.